# Вставка текста в текст combobox , который не является его элементом

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть combobox с элементами. Дело в том что при выборе элемента я хочу в текст combobox-a вставить некий другой текст. ну например `combobox.Text="zzz"`. Почему-то не получается. В чем причина, не смогли бы объяснить.

Самое интересное в breakpoint-e в свойстве Text="zzz", но вот в форме ничего не отображается.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void cboxScet_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { cboxScet.Text = "Нужный текст"; });
}
```